# The pagination issue of using Octopress with Github pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, octopress

I used Octopress to setup my blog with Github pages. Everything is OK. But I can't fix the pagination issues. Specifically, if I click the "older" link on my first blog page, it can't find the right page.

My Blog site is : 
http://www.enlangtech.com/blog/

And the corresponding repository is : https://github.com/sherlocktowne/sherlocktowne.github.io

Could you help me to fix it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not using the right variable for previous and next links.
It's `<a href="{{paginator.next_page_path}}">` and `<a href="{{paginator.previous_page_path}}">`.

See [Jekyll paginator documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/pagination/).